# How can I render a this design in reactJS and Redux with each item from a NoSQL db like pouchdb

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello I have just started learning how to use reactJS I am using the following example https://github.com/pgte/pouch-websocket-sync-example#readme 
my first goal is to have a template like the following [Design Objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwk3e.png)
I am not asking for a solution however I would like to be pointed in the right direction's
how to include  bootstrap based templates (and custom style sheets) In react and apply these styles to html elements inside a react component 
also how can I use multiple components and their Functions in a single page ? 
i'm still slightly confused about react

here is my target objective's
admin template with everything render server side with react <- this will be only the frontend and all data will be stored server side like the example.

all changes will be synced . I aim to use Nodejs or python tornado as server side api's

and include the grid based view with the rows being items from the mongodb or pouchdb store , each item once clicked will render a overlay with a table of TODO tasks , for example the grid could contain staff members and the todo list will be tasks for the staff member to complete

this question is mainly about the design

Comment: Please be very specific what you want to say. If you have multiple questions try splitting it because very few would read this big description.

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ instead of reinventing bootstrap in react, you could use that. When it comes to custom styling, that doesnt have anything to do with react. If youre running on webpack og browserify, just import the css file you want processed by webpack/browserify in your main-component

Comment: Hey thanks thsorens 
can someone mark this as answered ?